# Changing the PATH from a batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing a dos-batch in which I need to change the `PATH`.

I'm using the `SET` command.

The batch is run from the command line (`cmd.exe`).

The problem : the changes are only available for the cmd window, and I soon as this window is closed, the changes are dismissed.

How can I change the `PATH` from a batch and make sure the change will affect the whole system ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a tool `setx.exe` provided in the [Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en) that can be used to permanently change an environment variable from the command line:

```
setx path "%PATH%;C:\New Folder"
```

Source: http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm

The above link also gives the location of the registry keys that store the system / user environment variables - if you are feeling adventurous you could also try setting those.

User environment variables:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

System environment variables:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```